# Mongoose .count not working when nested?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Maybe I'm overlooking something but I have a pretty simple setup.  What I'm trying to do is find all 'App' documents in my database and then for each App get the number of User documents associated with that App.

```
AppObject.find({}).exec((err, apps) => {
  if (err) {

  } else if (!apps) {

  } else {
    apps.forEach((app, index) => {

      (function (app) {
        console.log('app ID ' + app._id);
        User.find({ appId: app._id }).count((countErr, count) => {
          console.log('COUNT ERR ' + JSON.stringify(countErr));
          console.log('Number of docs: ', count);
          // do more things with the App and the count
        });
      }(app));

    });
  }
});
```

When I look at the console logs, what I'm seeing is the line

```
console.log('app ID ' + app._id);
```

correctly prints the app ID, but then

```
console.log('Number of docs: ', count);
```

shows up as 0.

When I run the query outside of the forEach loop (and provide the app ID manually) it correctly returns the number of documents.

I'm kind of at a loss, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the easy mistake of assuming lines in NodeJS are executed in order.

Checkout some async articles explaining NodeJS event loop https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

What you'll find is the call to the database is returning after the first `for` loop has completed iterating.

Comment: Even though I have the second call to the database inside an immediate function?  I would have thought the call would be self contained

Comment: my initial answer is incorrect. but could it be that app._id is a different type than you are expecting? Mongoose returns back document references not JSON sometimes when you iterate over fields you are really over a representation. I would assign the query to a variable and make sure the queries are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I started recently working on project to migrate Nodejs from callback hell to Async/Await provided in latest Node version 8.x, please find the below solution and give it a shot. Thank you.

```
//Create a async/await function with ES6 syntax 
const findAllCount = async () => {
try{
  const apps = await AppObject.find({})
  await apps.forEach( app, async () => {
  console.log('app ID ' + app._id)
  const count = await User.find({ appId: await app._id }).count()
  console.log('Number of docs: ', count)
  // Here you can continue to use app and count for more things
 })
}
 catch(error){console.error('Error at findAllCount function: '+error)}
}

// Invoke Function
findAllCount()
```

Hope this helps. If not please provide the collection schema to reproduce scenario at my end. Thank you and wish all the best.